# How do I stop Python from ignoring certain functions?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I'm programming an AI assistant that is supposed to do many operations. I've programmed it,that numbers trigger the function that a part of the program is. However, I've run into a problem, when I added the function for my drawing tool,and translator. For the drawing tool,Python ignores it entirely. For the translator command,after asking the first two questions,instead of completing the code it loops back.How could I fix this? All the other functions work normally.

```
def turtledraw():
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.bgcolor("light blue")
    wn.title("Draw Time!")
    tt = turtle.Turtle()
    tt.forward(100)


def translatetime():
    langask1 = input("What do you want to translate?")
    langask2 = input("Type the first two letters of the language you want to translate to")
    translator= Translator(to_lang="{}".format(langask2))
    translation = translator.translate("{}".format(langask1))














while True:
    taker = taken()
    if "1" in taker:
         searcher = input("What would you like to Search?")
         webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=({})".format(searcher))
         print("Type Exit to do something else")
    if "Exit" in taker:
        taken()
        break
    if "Talk" in taker:
        talk_talk()

    if "3" in taker:
        wikifact_finder()
    if "4" in taker:
        answer_question()
    if "5" in taker:
        math_calculator()

    if "draw" in taker:
        turtledraw()
    if "9" in taker:
        translatetime()
```

Comment: What module is the `wn` variable from?

Comment: It's what I am calling the screen for the turtle drawing module.

Comment: Oh, I see. I haven't used the native turtle mode before! Cool! I'll read some more docs. After reviewing your question, for the translation, I think you need to print the translation after computing it.

Comment: For the drawing portion, I think you need to call `tt.mainloop()` or `tt.done()` to get the Screen to display to the user. https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.mainloop

Comment: After adding tt.mainloop() it throws an error,saying that "Turtle" object has no attribute mainloop. For the translation,it just prints out the the input of langask1,without translating.